# Read response after uploading attachment using Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to read response after uploading an attachment using web API c#. Getting below error:

no mediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'String' from content with media type 'multipart/form-data.

Here is my part of code:

string filepath = "C:/Users/O42895/Desktop/DownloadAttachmen20189t.jpg";
              string filename = "DownloadAttachmen20189t.jpg";

```
          MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
          ByteArrayContent fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath));
          fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = filename };
          content.Add(fileContent);

          client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("multipart/form-data"));

          response = await client.PostAsync("https:--.com/flex/upload/document/genericattachment", content);
```

var resBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                  Console.WriteLine(resBody);

I am getting the response but unable to print or read. Please let me know if any one knows

Comment: Why `await client.PostAsync` and then `ReadAsStringAsync().Result`? Why not `await` both?

Comment: you dont need :  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("multipart/form-data"));

Comment: I have removed that line but still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need to add the following line in your http header request on the client side (where you are sending the rest request to your web-api).

Hope this helps.

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried that but it didn't work. Now I have posted full code. Response is showing OK status but in quick watch its showing empty. Please check if u have any pointers